# Json Type Provider: using type as an argument in a function

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have a json document like this:

> {
>       "index": 1,
>       "addressOne": "1506 WAKE FOREST RD ",
>       "addressTwo": "RALEIGH NC 27604-1331",
>       "addressThree": " ",
>       "assessedValue": "$34,848",
>       "id": "c0e931de-68b8-452e-8365-66d3a4a93483",
>       "_rid": "pmVVALZMZAEBAAAAAAAAAA==",
>       "_ts": 1423934277,
>       "_self": "dbs/pmVVAA==/colls/pmVVALZMZAE=/docs/pmVVALZMZAEBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
>       "_etag": "\"0000c100-0000-0000-0000-54df83450000\"",
>       "_attachments": "attachments/"   }

I then load it via the type provider like this:

```
type HouseValuation = JsonProvider<"../data/HouseValuationSample.json">
```

When I try and use the HouseValuation as part of an argument, it is cast back to Object:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type `HouseValuation` is a root type that is used just to host the `Parse` and `Load` methods, but it is not a type that represents the actual parsed document. If you look at the type of `Load` or `Parse`, you'll see something like this:

```
Load : string -> JsonProvider<"...">.Root
```

So, the type of the actual parsed document is a nested type `Root` under the main provided type `HouseValuation`. The function should then take `HouseValuation.Root` as argument instead:

```
type HouseValuation = JsonProvider<" ... ">

let createSchoolAssignmentSearchCriteria(houseValuation:HouseValuation.Root) = 
  houseValuation.AddressOne
```

When you type `HouseValuation.` you'll see the two static methods and also all the nested types there (though in this example, there is only one record type).